# Expand a list of cases in a subclass

Tags: scala

Most probably what I want to do cannot be done, but hopefully something similar is possible.

What I would like to do is having a match-case statement in a method in a class `A`, creating a subclass `B` and keeping all the cases that are not overwritten by my subclass, so that before the final `case _` in the subclass all the cases of the superclass `A` are attempted.

AFAIK this is very far from being possible (but please correct me if wrong), but something similar is not that far from being possible.

A maybe possible option would be to have a map of cases and functions in the superclass and expanding that map in each subclass. The cases should be of the type `[T1] => Bool`, the functions should be of the type `[T1] => [T2]`, where `T2` is the return type of the method we are expanding in the subclass. Then a loop should be run until one case returns true and its function is executed.

The problem is that I am uncertain about how to define those cases (`[T1] => Bool`). Having a match for each one of them may be very inefficient. This may also be deeply non-idiomatic and some other way to implement this could be preferable.

Comment: So, in other words, it's something like a match statement, where there's such a `case _ => expr`, that `expr` is a match statement in itself? And, in the structural level, that statement should be modifiable by creating a new subclass? Can you provide a rough code sketch? It will be easier to understand what's your desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the problem in having the method in `B` call `super` on `case _`?

Comment: I was dreaming about something different but that sounds feasible and good. What if I have several traits implementing the same method and a class that extends parents with children and siblings? What would happen in that case?

Comment: @Trylks The first trait to implement it on the trait serialization would get it. After that, it's up to that trait, but calling super will continue up the serialization list, until it reaches the base class.

Answer (score 2):

While not quite a case statement, you can achieve a similar effect by modeling your logic as partial functions, and chaining them together with "orElse"

```
class A{
  def f={case foo:Foo => //do something
         case bar:Bar => //do something else}

}

class B extends B{
  override def f = {case bar:Bar=> //do something still different
                   } orElse super.f
}
```